# In handwritten digit recognition problem using logistic regression, what changes needed to add another class “Not a Digit”

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, pattern-recognition

In handwritten digit recognition problem using logistic regression, normal implementation would forcibly classify even a picture of dog or cat as a digit. To eliminate this, what changes are needed to add another class i.e. "Not a Digit" to already existing 10 classes (0 to 9) ?

Comment: I personally would start by adding letters as "letters".

Answer (score 0):

Such implementation would only require adding one more class for the target variable.

Further training data should have examples from the "Not A Digit" class as well(with appropriate label).